# HTML,CSS,JavaScript pop up issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I want a popup to be displayed in a particular format after clickon a button

I have a html code like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/headerIncludes.jsp"%>

<fmt:setBundle basename="regexPatterns" var="regexPatterns"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="pageLabels"/>

 <div id="modal-overlay" style="display:block"></div>
                        <div id="avfp-first-popup" class="modal" style="display:block;">
                            <h3 class="me-header">
                                <fmt:message key="fraud.popupOne" />
                            </h3>
                            <a id="me-no-first" class="me-btn"> <fmt:message
                                    key="generic.no" />
                            </a> <a id="me-yes-first" class="me-btn"> <fmt:message
                                    key="generic.yes" />
                            </a>
</div>




<un:useConstants var="constant" className="com.wu.pos.domain.PosConstants"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

and I have written a jquery function like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()){

    $('#releaseMTCN').click(function() {

    ('avfp-first-popup').show();




    });
```

But when I try to access the page before clicking the button the pop up is displaying. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#releaseMTCN').click(function() {
        $('avfp-first-popup').show();
    });
});
```

Try this. You forgot a `$`, and you didnt properly call your function.

Also, please learn to properly indent your code, so its easier to debug.